# How to print every byte of the memory a process is using in C?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory, memory-address

What I want to achieve is to start a process by starting a C command line application under Linux and then first find out which is the lowest and hightest virtual memory address used by the process and afterwards print every byte between as a hex value with printf(). Is that possible?

Can I even figure out which are the lowest and hightest virtual memory addresses of my own process?

If I had those, I guess I could use pointer arithmetic combined with printf("%p, &address) to print all thats between.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In which level, kernel or user?

Comment: You may access `/proc/self/psinfo` to get information you need but don't forget that some memory blocks are simply...garbage (blocks allocated then deallocated, for example) and knowledge abouot this is very tied with RT implementation). Also more organized data can be found on `/proc/self/maps` and `/proc/self/mem`. You may even (if supported by your kernel) directly read/copy `/proc/self/core`. For further details just check [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)

Comment: I'm in user level. Maybe I should clarify that my main problem is how I can read content at an absolute memory address.

Comment: Your virtual memory isn't guaranteed to be contiguously allocated. If you access a range that isn't mapped, you will segfault. If you want to access content at a virtual address, just assign that address to a pointer (e.g. `int* foo = (int*)0xDEADBEEF;`).

Comment: @slugonamission I haven't thought about that fact, but it makes sense now, thanks!

Comment: I got so far to read the first byte from the code area in memory of a 32 bit binary by doing this: `unsigned int *a = (unsigned int *) 0x08048000; printf("%02x\n", (char)*a);` That's the 7f from the ELF magic number.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ps` command as following

```
system("ps aux --sort -rss|grep <your_process_name_or_id>");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, how does this help find memory addresses?